# How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have dropdownlist, which I have filled from database. Now I need to get the selected value in Controller do some manipulation. But not getting the idea. Code which I have tried.

### Model

```
public class MobileViewModel 
{          
    public List<tbInsertMobile> MobileList;
    public SelectList Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
 public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails()
    {
        MobileViewModel MV = new MobileViewModel();
        MV.MobileList = db.Usp_InsertUpdateDelete(null, "", "", null, "", 4, MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
        MV.Vendor = new SelectList(db.Usp_VendorList(), "VendorId", "VendorName");
        return View(MV);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV)
    {           
        string strDDLValue = ""; // Here i need the dropdownlist value

        return View(MV);
    }
```

### View

```
   <table>           
        <tr>
            <td>Mobile Manufacured</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlVendor", Model.Vendor, "Select Manufacurer") </td>
        </tr>         
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You have bound your dropdown list to property `ddlVendor` but no such property exists in your model. Add a property `int SelectedVendor` or similar to your model and bind to that.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

### 1st Approach (via Request or FormCollection):

You can read it from `Request` using `Request.Form` , your dropdown name is `ddlVendor` so pass `ddlVendor` key in the formCollection to get its value that is posted by form:

```
string strDDLValue = Request.Form["ddlVendor"].ToString();
```

or Use `FormCollection`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV,FormCollection form)
{           
  string strDDLValue = form["ddlVendor"].ToString();

  return View(MV);
}
```

### 2nd Approach (Via Model):

If you want with Model binding then add a property in Model:

```
public class MobileViewModel 
{          
    public List<tbInsertMobile> MobileList;
    public SelectList Vendor { get; set; }
    public string SelectedVendor {get;set;}
}
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedVendor , Model.Vendor, "Select Manufacurer")
```

and in Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV)
{           
   string SelectedValue = MV.SelectedVendor;
   return View(MV);
}
```

### UPDATE:

If you want to post the text of selected item as well, you have to add a hidden field and on drop down selection change set selected item text in the hidden field:

```
public class MobileViewModel 
{          
    public List<tbInsertMobile> MobileList;
    public SelectList Vendor { get; set; }
    public string SelectVendor {get;set;}
    public string SelectedvendorText { get; set; }
}
```

use jquery to set hidden field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#SelectedVendor").on("change", function {
   $("#SelectedvendorText").val($(this).text());
 });
});
</script>

@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedVendor , Model.Vendor, "Select Manufacurer")
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedvendorText)
```

Comment: @Raghubar the second approach is more preffered so use Model binding

Comment: ok. and please also tell me how to set selected item in dropdownlist.

Comment: @Raghubar, Just set the value of property `SelectVender` in the controller to match the value of one of the options

Comment: this way in post action :``MV.Vendor = new SelectList(db.Usp_VendorList(), "VendorId", "VendorName",VM.SelectedVendor);`` the last parameter is used to set the selected value

Comment: @EhsanSajjad how to get the selected text ?

Comment: for that use jquery to set it in hidden field

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i used your update approach but i am getting all dropdown text in role. `var role = Request["SelectedText"].ToString();` any idea how to get selected text only.

Comment: @Steve what you mean by that? and how is your view code look like, related to ``SelectedText`` property

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectId, Model.Role, "Select Role", new { @class = "form-control" })` and `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedText)` and jquery is same as of yours

Comment: can you provide all the needed details in a new question, so i can have a look

Comment: Just if you name parameter in action  as select control name  it will pass the value when submit

Answer (score 13):

### Model

Very basic model with Gender field. `GetGenderSelectItems()` returns select items needed to populate DropDownList.

```
public enum Gender 
{
    Male, Female
}

public class MyModel
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGenderSelectItems()
    {
        yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" };
        yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" };
    }
}
```

### View

Please make sure you wrapped your `@Html.DropDownListFor` in a form tag.

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyController", "MyAction", FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, MyModel.GetGenderSelectItems())
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

### Controller

Your .cshtml Razor view name should be the same as controller action name and folder name should match controller name e.g `Views\MyController\MyAction.cshtml`.

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // shows your form when you load the page
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        // the value is received in the controller.
        var selectedGender = model.Gender;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

---

### Going further

Now let's make it strongly-typed and enum independent:

```
var genderSelectItems = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))
    .Cast<string>()
    .Select(genderString => new SelectListItem 
    {
        Text = genderString,
        Value = genderString,
    }).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: 'IEnumerable<Movie>' does not contain a definition for 'Gender' and no extension method 'Gender' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, Namespacex.Models.Movie.GetGenderSelectItems())
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

Comment: Got it. I have @model IEnumerable<AEXSoft.Models.Movie>. This is IEnumerable. How can I pass your code to IEnumerable?

Answer (score 6):

**MVC 5/6/Razor Pages**

I think the best way is with strongly typed model, because Viewbags are being aboused too much already :)

**MVC 5** example

**Your Get Action**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
    {
        var model = new RegistrationViewModel
        {
            Roles = GetRoles()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Your View Model**

```
    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? RoleId { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

**Your View**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
        <div class="col-form-txt">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleId, Model.Roles, "--Select Role--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Your Post Action**

```
    [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var _roleId = model.RoleId,
```

**MVC 6 It'll be a little different**

**Get Action**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register()
    {
        var _roles = new List<SelectListItem>();
        _roles.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
           Text = "Select",
           Value = ""
        });
        foreach (var role in GetRoles())
        {
          _roles.Add(new SelectListItem
          {
            Text = z.Name,
            Value = z.Id
          });
        }

        var model = new RegistrationViewModel
        {
            Roles = _roles
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Your **View Model** will be same as MVC 5

Your **View** will be like

```
<select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="Model.Roles"></select>
```

**Post** will also be same

**Razor Pages**

Your Page Model

```
[BindProperty]
public int User User { get; set; } = 1;

public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Roles = new List<SelectListItem> {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "X" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Y" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Z" },
   };
}

<select asp-for="User" asp-items="Model.Roles">
    <option value="">Select Role</option>
</select>
```

I hope it may help someone :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `@Html.DropDownList` , follow.

Controller:

```
var categoryList = context.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryName).ToList();

ViewBag.CategoryList = categoryList;
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(ViewBag.CategoryList), "Choose Category", new { @class = "form-control" })

$("#Category").on("change", function () {
 var q = $("#Category").val();

console.log("val = " + q);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something lightweight, I'd append a parameter to your action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowAllMobileDetails(MobileViewModel MV, string ddlVendor)
{           
    string strDDLValue = ddlVendor; // Of course, this becomes silly.

    return View(MV);
}
```

What's happening in your code now, is you're passing the first string argument of "ddlVendor" to `Html.DropDownList`, and that's telling the MVC framework to create a `<select>` element with a `name` of "ddlVendor." When the user submits the form client-side, then, it will contain a value to that key.

When MVC tries to parse that request into `MV`, it's going to look for `MobileList` and `Vendor` and not find either, so it's not going to be populated. By adding this parameter, or using `FormCollection` as another answer has suggested, you're asking MVC to specifically look for a form element with that name, so it should then populate the parameter value with the posted value.

Answer (score 1):

Use SelectList to bind @HtmlDropdownListFor and specify selectedValue parameter in it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553(v=vs.108).aspx

Example : you can do like this for getting venderid

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorId,Model.Vendor)


   public class MobileViewModel 
   {          
    public List<tbInsertMobile> MobileList;
    public SelectList Vendor { get; set; }
    public int VenderID{get;set;}
   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Action(MobileViewModel model)
   {
            var Id = model.VenderID;
```

Comment: @Raghubar - its not for you ..or for anyone ...I just want to know reason so that I can improve on...

Comment: @PranayRana, Cancelled it out - but must admit I was about to flag to close as a _link only answer_ before your edit - perhaps downvoter felt same

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue in asp.NET razor C#

I had a `ComboBox` filled with titles from an `EventMessage`, and I wanted to show the Content of this message with its selected value to show it in a label or `TextField` or any other `Control`...

My `ComboBox` was filled like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("EventBerichten", new SelectList(ViewBag.EventBerichten, "EventBerichtenID", "Titel"), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
```

In my `EventController` I had a function to go to the page, in which I wanted to show my `ComboBox` (which is of a different model type, so I had to use a partial view)?

The function to get from index to page in which to load the partial view:

```
  public ActionResult EventDetail(int id)
        {

            Event eventOrg = db.Event.Include(s => s.Files).SingleOrDefault(s => s.EventID == id);
            //  EventOrg eventOrg = db.EventOrgs.Find(id);
            if (eventOrg == null)
            {

                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.EventBerichten = GetEventBerichtenLijst(id);
            ViewBag.eventOrg = eventOrg;
            return View(eventOrg);
        }
```

The function for the partial view is here:

```
 public PartialViewResult InhoudByIdPartial(int id)
        {
            return PartialView(
                db.EventBericht.Where(r => r.EventID == id).ToList());

        }
```

The function to fill EventBerichten:

```
        public List<EventBerichten> GetEventBerichtenLijst(int id)
        {
            var eventLijst = db.EventBericht.ToList();
            var berLijst = new List<EventBerichten>();
            foreach (var ber in eventLijst)
            {
                if (ber.EventID == id )
                {
                    berLijst.Add(ber);
                }
            }
            return berLijst;
        }
```

The partialView Model looks like this:

```
@model  IEnumerable<STUVF_back_end.Models.EventBerichten>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            EventID
        </th>
        <th>
            Titel
        </th>
        <th>
            Inhoud
        </th>
        <th>
            BerichtDatum
        </th>
        <th>
            BerichtTijd
        </th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titel)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Inhoud)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BerichtDatum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BerichtTijd)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**VIEUW**: This is the script used to get my output in the view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#EventBerichten").change(function () {
            $("#log").ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                alert(exception);
            });

            var BerichtSelected = $("select option:selected").first().text();
            $.get('@Url.Action("InhoudByIdPartial")',
                { EventBerichtID: BerichtSelected }, function (data) {
                    $("#target").html(data);
                });
        });
    });
            </script>
@{
                    Html.RenderAction("InhoudByIdPartial", Model.EventID);
                } 

<fieldset>
                <legend>Berichten over dit Evenement</legend>
                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("EventBerichten", new SelectList(ViewBag.EventBerichten, "EventBerichtenID", "Titel"), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
                </div>

                <br />
                <div id="target">

                </div>
                <div id="log">

                </div>
            </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - this helped me to understand better ansd solve a problem I had.
The JQuery provided to get the text of selectedItem did NOT wwork for me
I changed it to

```
$(function () {
  $("#SelectedVender").on("change", function () {
   $("#SelectedvendorText").val($(**"#SelectedVender option:selected"**).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution not sure if this has been suggested or not. This also may not work for some things. That being said this is the simple solution below.

```
new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Waiting Invoices", Selected = true}

List<SelectListItem> InvoiceStatusDD = new List<SelectListItem>();
InvoiceStatusDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "All Invoices" });
InvoiceStatusDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Waiting Invoices", Selected = true});
InvoiceStatusDD.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Client Approved Invoices" });

@Html.DropDownList("InvoiceStatus", InvoiceStatusDD)
```

You can also do something like this for a database driven select list. you will need to set selected in your controller

```
@Html.DropDownList("ApprovalProfile", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["ApprovalProfiles"], "All Employees")
```

Something like this but better solutions exist this is just one method.

```
foreach (CountryModel item in CountryModel.GetCountryList())
    {
        if (item.CountryPhoneCode.Trim() != "974")
        {
            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.CountryName + " +(" + item.CountryPhoneCode + ")", Value = item.CountryPhoneCode });

        }
        else {


            countries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.CountryName + " +(" + item.CountryPhoneCode + ")", Value = item.CountryPhoneCode,Selected=true });

        }
    }
```