# How to send a selected value from view to Action method in ASP.NET MVC4 where DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here my approach is database first approach in MVC which have entity framework name "mvcEntity" and tblProducts is Products stored in my Database where DbContext has been disposed. I used ProductCode as my ValueField and ProductName as TextField for DropDownList.

//In Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetList()
    {
        using (mvcEntities objEntity = new mvcEntities())
        {
            List<tblProduct> Products = objEntity.tblProducts.ToList();
            ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(Products, "ProductCode",        "ProductName");
            return View(Products);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetList(string ProductCode)
    {
        //Get the Selected Dropdown Value an Dispaly in a table
        return View();
    }
```

// In View.cshtml:

```
  @using (@Html.BeginForm("GetList", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ProductLi" }))
  {  
  @Html.DropDownList("ProductList", "Select Product")`}
  <br />
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
     <th>Product Code</th>
     <th>Product Name</th>
     <th>Remarks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

[Html View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb6IB.jpg)

Comment: Your dropdownlist has the name `name="ProductList"`, but your method parameter name is `ProductCode` - they need to match - change one or the other. Then learn to start using view models and strongly bind to your model using the `XXXFor()` HtmlHelper methods

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc4/27901225#27901225

Answer (score 0):

First there is error in your code, your giving selected value to store in 'ProductList' but in the controller of post GetList you are giving variable ProductCode.
You can easily understand the process by following the below steps
1. DataBase

```
Table - tblProducts
    id   ProductCode    ProductName 
    1    name_x         name_x
    2    code_y         name_y
```

2. In controller side
    a. If we are not fetching data from db and then in the [HttpGet] method do like the following

```
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult GetList()
            {
                ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(db.tblProducts, "ProductCode", "ProductName");
                return View();

            }
```

3. In the view
   import model in the view page at the top of page `@model ProjectName.Models.ModelName`
`@Html.DropDownList("ProductList", "Select Product")`
4. Then in the controller, to receive the selected data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetList(string ProductList)
{
    //your selected value will stored in the ProductList variable
    return View();
}
```

5. edit the model file as below

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace ProjectName.Models
{
     public class tblProduct 
     { 
         public string ProductCode { get; set; } 
         public string ProductName { get; set; } 
         public string SBU { get; set; } 
     } 
 }
```

hope this helps

Comment: no.The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Comment: without DB, it's working, but I should get the details from DB.

Comment: you said that your dbcontext is disposed so that i changed the code. Now you want to post an answer with db connection

Comment: its getting a error. The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed on .cshtml page

Comment: you should import the model for the view page. see the updated code

Comment: you are delaying to much

Comment: using System;
      using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class tblProduct
    {
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string SBU { get; set; }
    }

Comment: first remove partial from the class

Answer (score -1):

You can Highlight the value which you want to be select

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetList(int? ProductList)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry for miss understanding you can use 'GetList(int? ProductList)' into your post method to get the selected value form dropdownlist.

Comment: 'int?' is used if your productcode is integer other then you may use string also instead of int?,

Answer (score -1):

// ActionMethod

```
public ActionResult GetList()
    {
        using (mvcEntities objEntity = new mvcEntities())
        {
            List<tblProduct> Products = objEntity.tblProduct.ToList();
            ViewBag.ProductList = new SelectList(Products, "ProductCode", "ProductName");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

// In View

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetList", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
if (ViewBag.Pro != null)
{
@Html.DropDownList("Pro", "Select Product")}
}
 <br />
 <input type="submit" name="btnSub" id="btnSub" value="Submit" /> 
 }

 @{
 mvcEntity objEntity = new mvcEntity();
 int ProCode = 0;
 if (Request["Pro"] != null)
 {
    ProCode = int.Parse(Request["Pro"]);
    tblProduct pmd = objEntity.tblProduct.Where(x => x.ProductCode == ProCode).FirstOrDefault();
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@pmd.ProductId</td>
            <td>@pmd.ProductCode</td>
            <td>@pmd.ProductName</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

}

Comment: remember always you should place controller code in view page. its not a good pracyice

Answer (score -2):

ypu should use Viewbag.ProductList instead of direct calling.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("GetList", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ProductLi" }))
{  
@Html.DropDownList("ViewBag.ProductList", "Select Product")`}
<br />
<table border="1">
<tr >
  <th>Product Code</th>
 <th>Product Name</th>
 <th>Remarks</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```