# ASP.NET mvc DropDownListFor pass type to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to pass SelectedItem from DropDownListFor to `public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel indexViewModel)`. After submit i have `emp=null`.
What i should place instead of `"Number"` in `IndexViewModel.ListOfEmployee = new SelectList(ListOfEmployee, "Number", "Name");`

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Employee> ListOfEmployee = new List<Employee>();
        ListOfEmployee.Add(new Employee { Name = "Jhon", Number = 1 });
        IndexViewModel IndexViewModel = new IndexViewModel();
        IndexViewModel.ListOfEmployee = new SelectList(ListOfEmployee, "Number", "Name");

        return View(IndexViewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel indexViewModel)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.emp ,Model.ListOfEmployee)

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public SelectList ListOfEmployee { get; set; }

    public Employee emp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc4)

Comment: You cannot bind a `<select>` element to a complex obect (typeof `Employee`). You property `emp` need to be type `int` - `public int emp { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep a simple value type property to store the selected dropdown option value.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public SelectList ListOfEmployee { get; set; }    
    public int SelectedEmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedEmployeeId, Model.ListOfEmployee)
```

and in your HttpPost action, access this `SelectedEmployeeId` property which will give you the number corresponding to the selected name. If you want the complete employee object, you should query the db again with the number(id)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    var selectedNumber= model.SelectedEmployeeId; 
    return View();
}
```