# Pass dropdownlist value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist and want to pass value in Controller. View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
    @Html.DropDownList("dropOrg", ViewBag.dropOrg as SelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

Controller

```
foreach (int tmp in org)
{
   string s = tmp + " - " + orgNames[tmp];
   SelectListItem item1 = new SelectListItem() { Text = s, Value = tmp.ToString() };
   items.Add(item1);
}
ViewBag.dropOrg = items;
```

What should i do?

Comment: How about taking a [tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/asp-net-mvc-populating-dropdown-lists-in-razor-views-using-the-mvvm-design-pattern-entity-framework-and-ajax)?

Comment: I would suggest using a DropDownListFor for this. If set on this, I would go with calling a javasript function and using jquery to get the value. Passing it to the controller using an ajax.

Comment: Is there any easyer way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get DropDownList SelectedValue in Controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you create ViewModel for your View:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string DropDownListValue { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller's get method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var org = GetOrg(); //your org
    var orgNames = GetOrgNames(); //your orgNames

    // . . .

    ViewBag.DropDownListValue = new SelectList(org.Select(s => 
    new SampleViewModel 
    {  
        DropDownListValue = $"{s} - {orgNames[s]}"
    }, "DropDownListValue", "DropDownListValue");
    return View(new SampleViewModel())
}
```

your `SomeAction` View:

```
@model YourAppNamespace.SampleViewModel
<h1>Hello Stranger</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("DropDownListValue")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

**Note that:**

> The `DropDownList` helper used to create an HTML select list
>   requires a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, either explicitly or
>   implicitly. That is, you can pass the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`
>   explicitly to the `DropDownList` helper or you can add the
>   `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to the `ViewBag` using the same name for
>   the `SelectListItem` as the model property.

We have used here implicit passing, that is we have used same name for `SelectListItem` and `ViewBag` (which is `DropDownListValue`).

Then when you hit `Submit`, you need `HttpPost` method for `SomeAction`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SampleViewModel model)
{
    var org = GetOrg(); //your org
    var orgNames = GetOrgNames(); //your orgNames

    //. . . Validation etc..

    ViewBag.DropDownListValue = new SelectList(org.Select(s => 
    new SampleViewModel 
    {  
        DropDownListValue = $"{s} - {orgNames[s]}"
    }, "DropDownListValue", "DropDownListValue", model.DropDownListValue);


    var doSomething = model.DropDownListValue; //Your selected value from DropDownList
    return View(model)
}
```

References: **[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9lfjtM)**, 
**[Using the DropDownList Helper with ASP.NET MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)**