# DropDownList not passing values to my controller

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have successfully populated my drop down list using a dropdownlistfor html helper, however when I submit the form the selected items value is not being passed with the model into the action result. Here is my code sample

Customer Model

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(11)]
    [Display(Name="Date of birth")]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsLetter { get; set; }

    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Membership type")]
    public MembershipType MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

MembershipType Model

```
public class MembershipType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short SignUpFee { get; set; }
        public byte DurationInMonths { get; set; }
        public byte DiscountRate { get; set; }
    }
```

Customer View Model

```
   public class NewCustomerViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable <MembershipType>MembershipTypes { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model MovieApp.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Customer</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers"))

{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.BirthDate)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Customer.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipType)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MembershipType
    ,new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id","Name")
    ,"Select Membership Type"
    ,new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>


<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsLetter) Subscribed to newsletter?
    </label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Action

```
public ActionResult New()
        {
            var  DBmebershipTypes= _context.MembershipTypes.ToList();
            var ViewModel = new NewCustomerViewModel()
            {
                MembershipTypes = DBmebershipTypes

            };
            return View(ViewModel);
        }
```

Post Action

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
        {
             _context.Customers.Add(customer);
             _context.SaveChanges();
             return RedirectToAction("Index", "Customers");
        }
```

When I debug the program, all inputed values are in memory, but the moment it has to be saved to database, dropdownlist selection doesent get saved.

Comment: Please see this already give answer in this post : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901175/how-to-get-dropdownlist-selectedvalue-in-controller-in-mvc/27901225)

Comment: @HirenPatel no there is no answer to this question in that post

Answer (score 1):

Update your `Customer` Class you have wrong type for MembershipTypeId set it to `int` hopefully this'll work for you.

```
[Display(Name = "Membership type")]
public int MembershipTypeId { get; set; }
```