# Viewbag not properly working transfer the wrong data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, viewbag

I am student. I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I google it and I tried see I write all code but viewbag not properly working

I am transferring data and using the viewing but not transferring the dropdown value

`type.cs`

```
public class Type
{
    //public int Value { get; set; }
    //public string Text { get; set; }

    public int typeid { get; set; }
    public string typename { get; set; }
}

public class TypeViewModel
{
    //public List<Type> TypeDetaills { get; set; }

    public SelectList TypeList { get; set; }

}
```

`HomeControlle.cs`

```
TypeViewModel TypeViewModel = new TypeViewModel();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getType", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cn.Open();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    List<Type> objcountry = new List<Type>();
    SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "typeid", "typename", 0);
    TypeViewModel.TypeList = objlistofcountrytobind;

    ViewBag.typename = TypeViewModel.TypeList;
    cn.Close();

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCustomer(Customer customer,string TypeList)
{
    customer.Type = TypeList;
    customer.CustomerName = cust;
       
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

`Index.cshtml`

```
@model projectname.Models.TypeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    //var t = ViewBag.typename;
}

<h2>Type Query</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCustomer", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { TypeList = @ViewBag.typename }))
{
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
            <label>Type Name:</label>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeList, ViewBag.typename as SelectList)

            @*@Html.Hidden("TypeList", @ViewBag.typename);*@

            @*@Html.HiddenFor("TypeList", @ViewBag.typename);*@
            @*@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TypeList)*@

            @*<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.typename" />*@

            @*@Html.DropDownList("typeid", t as SelectList)*@
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.typename, new SelectList((IEnumerable<Type>)t, "typeid", "typename"))*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label>Customer Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="cust" name="cust" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

see i select the runtime `warranty` from the drop down

[image]

[image]

I am trying to pass controller `warranty` not `2`

see stored procedure `getType` fill this stored procedure in dropdown

[image]

I tried hiddenfor attribute but it not work

I want the pass `warranty` to `createcustomer` controller not `2`

please help

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to create code, you have to learn that the first letter in MVC is for model. So you have forget that viewbag is even exist. Create a view model , assign data  and pass it from the action and use it inside of the view

```
  TypeViewModel.TypeList = objlistofcountrytobind;
  return View (TypeViewModel)
```

and you can only assign as a hidden (or not hidden) the primitive types (as string or int) not the whole instanse of the class

Comment: can you help me more ```you have to learn that the first letter in MVC is for model.``` i am not understood this sentence

Comment: @Developer This is why you have to start from the tutorials, not from trying to create the code. You will never learn otherwise.

Comment: can you give best tutorial link to adopt the code easy way i write the logic in notebook and perform the code on laptop and facing error i am google it can you provide what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `text` and `value` field same, if you want the `text` field to be posted back to the controller action method. By default `dropdownlist` uses `value` field.
Change that line!

`SelectList objlistofcountrytobind = new SelectList(dt.AsDataView(), "typename", "typename", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your view model as described in the following post: [How to get `DropDownList` SelectedValue in Controller in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27901175/6630084).

Or you can use the JavaScript:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeList,
    ViewBag.type_name as SelectList,
    new { onchange=" { var ddltext = $(`#TypeList option:selected`).text();$('#textvalue').val(ddltext);}" }) 

@Html.Hidden("typeList", "")

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```